# How to get the related searches from the YouTube, Yandex and Bing

Tags: c#, youtube, bing, yandex

I am working on a project and I have to get the total results against a search query and Finding the related searches. I have got the total number of searches using the HTML Agility pack from all the above mentioned browsers.

What I am not getting is that the related searches against a search query for example when we start typing a word in the YouTube search bar there comes the IntelliSense in the search bar. That's what I want. I have tried it many times but that's not working.The compiler says value can't be null.

Here's the results which I wants.
[The elipse showing the required results which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut9ih.png)

That's the result which I wants in all the browsers.
Can I get it in someway?

Here's my Code : 
[Here's the code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6kOH.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: The high-level description of an auto-complete dropdown and the low-level error report "The compiler says value can't be null." are extremely far from each other; I suggest you add some excerpt of the code where the exception occurs for other users to make sense of the problem.

Comment: Code snapshot uploaded Please take a view

Comment: I have got the suggestions using suggestionApi's for bing,Google and youtube.

Comment: But didn't find it for the yandex search Engine